# How can I report on files with pending changes in TFS?

Tags: reporting-services, tfs

I'd like to create a simple report that shows files that currently have pending changes (checked out) from a TFS 2008 server. I know that I can use the "Find in Source Control" option from Team Explorer, but I would rather generate a reporting services report. Ideally, I'd be able to show when the file was checked out and the user that checked it out, but that's not imperative.

If the data isn't pushed to the TFS data warehouse by default, then I'd like to find the relational table(s) in the SQL Server instance that would need to be queried.

I've spent some time digging around the TFS data warehouse and looking at all of the canned Reporting Services reports that I can get my hands on, but everything seems to be geared towards work items, check-ins associated with work items, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt the information you're looking for is in the data warehouse and even if it was it might not be fresh enough for your purposes.  By default the warehouse is updated once an hour.

You could use SSRS to report directly against the TFSVersionControl database but I would not recommend going this route.  The database is not documented and chances are very good that it will change in the next version.  It could also have performance implications if your queries are not written correctly.

A better solution would be to use the TFS web services as your SSRS data source.  There are services you can call to get all files that are checked out.  This iformation is always current and the queries it runs are highly optimized.

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for some easy to read data and not too worried about print outs, have a look at the TFS sidekick application by Attrice.  Very helpful and if you have the correct permissions, you'll be able to see all the checked out files.

http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/

Comment: Thanks Ray. I have tried the sidekicks and can get the list from team explorer. I was hoping to get into Reporting Services so I can subscribe to a weekly report and control what columns are displayed.

Answer (score 2):

Example command line (Studio 2008):

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\tf.exe" status /recursive /user:*
```