# determine who has what files checked out

Tags: version-control, vcs-checkout

In **TFS 2010**, how can I figure out which **user** has what **files** *checked out*?

This question excludes going folder by folder looking within each one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I report on files with pending changes in TFS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/539160/how-can-i-report-on-files-with-pending-changes-in-tfs)

Comment: @EdwardThomson I disagree that this is a duplicate of the other question. This question is about finding who has files checked out, which the power tools do quite well. The other question is about producing a weekly report using SSRS. Whilst the end result might be similar (a list of users who have pending changes) the desired output format is completely different. For day to day usage the reporting services solution is overkill and would require time to code a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install the [TFS 2010 power tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f), then in source control explorer right click on any folder and select "Find in Source Control". You can now search for all checked out files, and filter by user id

Answer (score 1):

```
tf status /login:UserName
```

This [status command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9s5ae285.aspx) and many other helpful tips can be found on [How to force undo checkout? #TFS](http://fci-h.blogspot.com/2011/01/how-to-force-undo-checkout-tfs.html).